# Must an Embedded Bokeh Server in a Flask App run on a Tornado web server?

Tags: flask, bokeh

I'm hitting a limitation with using the Tornado server due to its single threaded nature (from the [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html) it is a *non-blocking, single-threaded HTTP server.*). I'd like to use the Python `requests` module to fetch some model data that my Flask app serves by returning content through jsonify calls. The trouble is that the server in the process of rendering the Bokeh document and is hung up on that execution path making it busy to handle another request on top of the one it has not yet finished. (Code that details this issue can be found here... [Code 503 in Flask with Embedded Bokeh Server App fetching jsonified data through requests.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401185/code-503-in-flask-with-embedded-bokeh-server-app-fetching-jsonified-data-through)).

As a work around I'd like to see if its possible to pursue another web server to serve my embedded bokeh app with around Flask. **What exactly is driving the restrictions between Bokeh and the Tornado?**. The embedding section comes off quite dedicated to Tornado so how constrained are the things mentioned in this section...

> [Embedding Bokeh Server as a
>   Library](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library)
>
> It can be useful to embed the Bokeh Server in a larger *Tornado
>   application*, or the Jupyter notebook, and *use the already existing
>   Tornado IOloop*... It is also possible to *create and control an
>   IOLoop directly*. This can be useful to create standalone “normal”
>   python scripts that serve Bokeh apps, or to embed a Bokeh application
>   into a framework like Flask or Django *without having to run a
>   separate Bokeh server process*.

Where can I find information about the dependency on Tornado and **is it possible to embed Bokeh with Flask all running on a different WSGI server, preferably a multi-threaded server?**

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but I have had similar questions with Pyramid integration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400581/how-do-i-integrate-a-bokeh-server-into-a-pyramids-application The answer there may lead you to the correct path. I hope it's useful.

Comment: @Thornhale I'm basically following his examples with the flask embed stuff as you see in my linked question about the Code 503. My flask app is working, I was just trying to get around the problem discovered in the Code 503 question. Check it out, you'll see a good usage for embedding Flask including parameter passing and what not.